# FFmpeg - how to convert pictures to mp4?

Tags: command-line

i´m using ubuntu and want to create a .mp4 file with some pictures I have this error:

```
width not divisible by 2 (5333x3000)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I try to convert with this :

```
unoconv -f pdf test1.pptx && convert -density 400 test1.pdf picture.png && ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -i picture-%01d.png -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unnecessary ffmpeg options.

```
#!/bin/bash
unoconv -f pdf test1.pptx
convert -density 400 test1.pdf picture.png
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i picture-%01d.png test.mp4
```

or

```
unoconv -f pdf test1.pptx; convert -density 400 test1.pdf picture.png; ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i picture-%01d.png test.mp4
```

---

Instead of this:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -i picture-%01d.png -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

use this instead:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i picture-%01d.png test.mp4
```